# how to run pyrogram client as an event listener

Tags: event-loop, pyrogram

I'm trying to run some functions alongside the pyrogram client as an event listener application. I tried the following code, but the handler was never invoked. I guess it is because the event loop does not dispatch the while loop, so the thread was never released back to run the handler. but is there a way to properly do this?

```
async def run_tele():
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(handle, filters=filters.text))
    await app.start()
    while True:
       # do something here
      time.sleep(1)
    await app.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(run_tele())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're starting the client (`app.start()`), but never actually give it an opportunity to listen for events. Call `pyrogram.idle()` so that Pyrogram keeps the Client alive and listens for updates from Telegram.

Alternatively you can also use `app.run()`, which will `start()`, `idle()`, and `stop()` for you.

Comment: Which line in idle() calls the listening thing? I don't see it. From what I read, it just creates infinite sleep main thread tasks.  app.run() works but it blocks, so no while loop.

Comment: try this https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/updates#using-add-handler .